# How can I wrap Jupyter output in custom HTML?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I want to be able to take the normal output for an object and insert it into custom HTML components. Specifically, I want to allow things like putting several charts into an accordion UI element, or having hidden dataframes that are shown when a button is clicked. Is there a way to get the HTML that would normally be output, wrap it in my own HTML components, and then output that?

I have tried:

```python
import IPython.display as dp

dp.display(dp.HTML('<div id="mycontainer">')) # Just a simple div, 
                                              # but ideally would be e.g. bootstrap component
dp.display(my_obj) # my_obj here could be a (potentially styled) dataframe 
                   # or a plot from matplotlib/altair/etc.
dp.display(dp.HTML('</div>'))
```

However, the unclosed `<div>` just gets automatically closed, so `my_obj` doesn't get inserted into it. Some objects have `_repr_html_()`, but not all do (particularly charts). Still, Jupyter obviously has some way of extracting HTML from arbitrary objects.

It seems from trying to read the source that `nbconvert` is used to change the object to HTML, but I'm not sure if A) I'm understanding that right or B) how to get HTML from an arbitrary object that is not in a notebook node object (or how to construct such an object myself).

Answer (score 1):

this seams to work for me :

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

myString = 'Hello, world!'
prependHtmlTag = '<h1>'
appendHtmlTag = '</h1>'
display(HTML(prependHtmlTag + myString + appendHtmlTag )
```

just put any html formated string in the `display(HTML([yourString]))`